# Why Azure VM Restore operation leads to Backup operation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault

I use Recovery Service Vault to restore VM. After selecting "Restore point" and activating "Replace existing" operation, I go to "View all jobs" page and can see that immediately after "Restore" operation a "Backup" operation is started. I cannot find any documentation on why this is the case. For what reason this backup operation is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as part of replace disks functionality, we take an on-demand backup before replacing the disks so that any error in the restore operation, we can roll back the operation and keep the source VM clean.

As per [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#replace-existing-disks-from-a-restore-point],
"During replace existing disk(s) operations, as a precautionary measure, we backup the data before initiating the replace disks operations."

Answer (score 1):

These might what you are looking for when you replace existing disks from a restore point:

- [Backup for restored VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#backup-for-restored-vms)

> If you restored a VM to the same resource group with the same name as
>   the originally backed-up VM, backup continues on the VM post restore.
>   If you restored the VM to a different resource group or you specified
>   a different name for the restored VM, the VM is treated as if it's a
>   new VM. You need to set up backup for the restored VM.

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks for the answer. Quoted text might be an answer to my question, but as for me this MSDN documentation is very unclear. It does not explains why (for what reason) "backup continues on the VM post restore". In my case backup occurs even if restore operation fails soon, so I get extra backup for no apparent reason and have to either cancel it or wait for an hour while it finishes. In my understanding "post restore" means "after restore completed", but in practice backup is started in parallel with the restore operation.

Comment: Backup continued on the VM post restore might be the backup policy you have set when you back up the VM before. You can see the job details-"Recovery Point Expiry Time in UTC" from the backup job. Per my understanding, the backup job will continue till the expiry time.